# IIS Application Pool identity problem

Tags: iis, application-pools

I'm having a problem with an identity pool on a new IIS server.

Here's my Event viewer text:

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   W3SVC
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1021
Date:       6/12/2009
Time:       1:44:50 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   <scrubbed>
Description:
The identity of application pool, '<scrubbed>' is invalid.  If it remains invalid when the first request for the application pool is processed, the application pool will be disabled.  The data field contains the error number.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 69 05 07 80               i..?
```

Google suggests that it's something to do with the user of the app pool which I set in the "Identity" tab. The most common problems are:

1. Setting the wrong password
2. Not adding the user to the IIS_WPG group

I've tried and retried both of these (and restarted the IIS service), and nothing seems to be fixing it. What other things should I be looking for.

FWIW, the identity user is a domain (not local) user. This same setup is working fine on another (supposedly identical) server/setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to MattB, [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863537/asp-net-error-the-identity-of-application-pool-is-invalid) eventually led me to the right answer (for me).

I ran the following command (from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727):

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -GA domain\username
```

...where domain\username was the domain-qualified username (in the standard Windows format) of the user I was using for the app pool's identity.

From the aspnet_regiis help, the -GA option does:

```
Grant the specified user or group access to the IIS
metabase and other directories used by ASP.NET.
```

I don't know why this wasn't done automatically on this server (as I've never had to do this in the past).

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark, but perhaps the domain account you've configured for the App Pool's identity is locked?

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the account "Logon as a Service" rights as well. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863537/asp-net-error-the-identity-of-application-pool-is-invalid) is a very similar question from stack overflow.

Comment: It wasn't "Logon as Service", but the Stack Overflow question you linked to gave me the right answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IIS6, with the Metabase Explorer (in the [resource kit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840671)), you can do the following:

- browse to /LM/W3SVC/AppPools/MyAppPool
- enable "View/Secure data"
- (if needed) enable "View/Inherited data"

Now, look at the WAMUserName and WAMUserPass.  You can try running processes as that user:

```
runas /user:myuser cmd.exe
```

If that does not work, you should be closer to the answer.